# django-simple-history cannot import name error for model import in management command

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I am using django-simple-history for maintaining the history for each model. Now when I import the model in my management command it gives

> import error "cannot find import name 'ModelName'".

Any Help regarding this.?

Comment: Post your management command file

Comment: from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from api.v1.restaurants.models import Restaurant
from api.v1.restaurants.utils import convert_to_e164
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
import json
from django.db import transaction
from django.db.models import Q
import random


"""
change logic accordingly in rating
"""

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):

Comment: "api.v1.restaurants.models import Restaurant "  this is line which causes the error. the name matches. it goes to the model if i click on it

Comment: I downgraded django-simple-history to 1.2.0 and it started working. Not happy with the solution though cause i am using django 1.6.7

Answer (score 3):

To track history for a model and fix ur issues to use of this code.

pip install django-simple-history